# ARM Cortex M3 Hard Fault when writing to NVIC Registers

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m

Whenever I write to the register of the Interrupt Controller in my Cortex-M3 a hard fault interrupt is generated.

I assume it has to do with the MPU not being configured.
I am working off a basic metal demo with startup code for a Cortex-M3.
Here is how the MPU is being configured and the bits I added at the end

```
  /* Configure region 1 to cover VECTORS and CODE (Executable, Read-only) */
/* Start address, Region field valid, Region number */
SCS.MPU.RegionBaseAddr = ((unsigned int) &Image$$VECTORS$$Base) | REGION_VALID | 1;
/* Access control bits, Size, Enable */
SCS.MPU.RegionAttrSize = RO | CACHEABLE | BUFFERABLE | REGION_16K | REGION_ENABLED;

/* Configure a region to cover DATA in RAM (Executable, Read-Write) */
SCS.MPU.RegionBaseAddr = ((unsigned int) &Image$$DATA$$Base) | REGION_VALID | 2;
SCS.MPU.RegionAttrSize = FULL_ACCESS | CACHEABLE | BUFFERABLE | REGION_8K | REGION_ENABLED;

/* Configure a region to cover Heap and Main Stack (Not Executable, Read-Write) */
SCS.MPU.RegionBaseAddr = ((unsigned int) &Image$$ARM_LIB_STACKHEAP$$Base) | REGION_VALID | 3;
SCS.MPU.RegionAttrSize = NOT_EXEC | FULL_ACCESS | CACHEABLE | BUFFERABLE | REGION_4K | REGION_ENABLED;

/* Configure a region to cover Process Stack (Not Executable, Read-Write) */
SCS.MPU.RegionBaseAddr = ((unsigned int) &Image$$PROCESS_STACK$$ZI$$Base) | REGION_VALID | 4;
SCS.MPU.RegionAttrSize = NOT_EXEC | FULL_ACCESS | CACHEABLE | BUFFERABLE | REGION_4K | REGION_ENABLED;

SCS.MPU.RegionBaseAddr = ((unsigned int)0x40000000) | REGION_VALID | 5;
SCS.MPU.RegionAttrSize = NOT_EXEC | FULL_ACCESS | REGION_512K | REGION_ENABLED;

SCS.MPU.RegionBaseAddr = ((unsigned int)0xE000E000) | REGION_VALID | 6;
SCS.MPU.RegionAttrSize = NOT_EXEC | P_RW_U_NA  | REGION_4K | REGION_ENABLED;
```

I added the bottom 2 regions. The second last is for peripheral address space and this allows me to write to those registers without causing an error.
The last region is the one I added for reading and writing to the NVIC controller.

This is the exact line that is causing the crash.

```
pNVIC->SETEN=0x10;//enables UART int2010                       
movs    r0,#0x10
mov     r1,#-0x1FFF2000 // R1 has the base address of NVIC 0xE000E000
str     r0,[r1,#0x100] //the SETEN register has an offset of 256 bytes
```

As soon as the debugger executes the last STR instruction the exception occurs

Could someone help me to configure the MPU to write to the NVIC registers of the M3?

Here's how my scatter file looks.

```
LOAD_REGION 0x00000000 0x00005000
; for Keil MCBSTM32 use : LOAD_REGION 0x20000000 0x00005000
{
VECTORS +0 0x400    ; maximum of 256 exceptions (256*4 bytes == 0x400)
{
exceptions.o (vectors, +FIRST)     ; from exceptions.c
}

; Code is placed immediately (+0) after the previous root region
; (so code region will also be a root region)
CODE +0 0x4000-0x400
{
* (+RO)           ; All program code, including library code
}

DATA 0x20004000 0x2000
{
* (+RW, +ZI)      ; All RW and ZI data
}

; Heap grows upwards from start of this region and
; Stack grows downwards from end of this region
; The Main Stack Pointer is initialized on reset to the top addresses of this region
ARM_LIB_STACKHEAP 0x20006000 EMPTY 0x1000
{
}


PROCESS_STACK 0x20007000 EMPTY 0x1000
{
}

; System Control Space registers
SCS_REGION 0xE000E000 UNINIT 0x1000
{
scs.o(scs_registers)
}
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without more information.  For example, we don't have the #defines for P_RW_U_NA and FULL_ACCESS (they would probably be obvious from the datasheet, true...)  That's one obvious difference, have you tried that?  (Even if you want more/less restrictive access than the other regions eventually).  Also, if I were you, I would step through at the assembly level and make sure the 2 lines are writing to **exactly** the effective address you think they are.  Is pNVIC initialized?  Is it getting corrupted?  Is the struct layout correct?  etc.

Comment: I updated the exact line of assembly that causes the crash. My basic question still remains, does the address range that I am trying to write to need to be setup in the MPU? If so how do I do that exactly?

Comment: Without the #defines, I can't say with 100% certainty, but it looks like you are configuring region 6 writes to be "off limits" to non-privileged users.  This is the region where the NVIC is mapped.  So when you try to enable the UART interrupt, the write to the NVIC generates a fault.  Please try replacing "`P_RW_U_NA`" with "`FULL_ACCESS`" for region 6 (setting `AP[2:0]` to `11`).